# SQL server database port parameter in configuration file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to install `SQL Server 2016` using configuration file. Instead of using Instance name, I am trying to use database port (1433) to install the Server. The parameter name for Instance name in the configuration file is `INSTANCENAME`. Could someone tell what is the database port parameter name?

I see parameters like `COMMFABRICPORT` and `MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT`, but I am not sure if it is the database port which I am looking for.

Comment: Interface settings (as in, what protocols to enable, using which addresses and what ports) aren't part of setup -- you can't specify those in the setup GUI either. There's a bunch of other things you can't pre-configure this way, like startup trace flags. If you want to configure these programmatically, you'll have to do it after the installation, using [SMO](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.wmi?view=sqlserver-2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port 1433 are default on SQL Server. You don't need change if you want to use this port, but, remember, you can change the port on SQL Server Configuration Manager.

If you Need to generate the configuration file, please follow this step:

**How to generate a configuration file**

1. Insert the SQL Server installation media. From the root folder, double-click Setup.exe.

> ```
> Note
> SQL Server Express Edition setup does not create a configuration file automatically.
> ```

**The following command will start setup and create a configuration file.**

SETUP.exe /UIMODE=Normal /ACTION=INSTALL

2. Follow the wizard through to the Ready to Install page. The path to the configuration file is specified in the Ready to Install page in the configuration file path section.
3. Cancel the setup without actually completing the installation, to generate the INI file.

This steps will create a configuration file for you.

Comment: I am using `inno setup` to install the SQL server. The port number can be 1433 or any other configured port. The thing is I have to specify this in the configuration ini file before the installation starts as it will be a silent installation.